# PhantomJS not returning value of input

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to get the value out of `<input type="hidden" id="exampleID" name="example" value="exampleValue">` from a website using phantomJS. After doing some research I found this method, but it doesn't seem to work for me:

```
var system = require('system');
var page   = require('webpage').create();
var url    = system.args[1];
page.open(url, function () {
  console.log(document.getElementById('exampleID').value);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

When running it, I get nothing. If I type `console.log(document.getElementById('exampleID').value)` in my browser's console, I get the desired output. Also if I change the js to console.log(page.content), I get the whole page source, but my desired value is still missing. My guess is that it is because of the hidden attribute. How can I make phantomjs output the value of a hidden object?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `page.onConsoleMessage`:

```
var system = require('system');
var url    = system.args[1];

var page   = require('webpage').create();
page.onConsoleMessage = function (str) {
  console.log(str);
};

page.open(url, function () {
  console.log(document.getElementById('exampleID').value);
  phantom.exit();
});
```